# Is adding the message itself to the hash stronger than the hash

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

I've been reading up on how Python constructs a random seed from the user input. The relevant bit of code is shown below

```
    elif version == 2 and isinstance(a, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        if isinstance(a, str):
            a = a.encode()
        a = int.from_bytes(a + _sha512(a).digest(), 'big')
```

In particular my question is why the code takes the user input itself, and adds it to the hash, instead of just using the hash itself. Does this provide a better seed, or has other programming benefits? The alternative in my view would just be to use the digest from the hash

```
    a = int.from_bytes(_sha512(a).digest(), 'big')
```

Python uses the mersenne twister as its random number generator, which needs to be properly initialized. I fail to see how `a + _sha512(a).digest()` provides a better seed over just `a_sha512(a).digest()`

Comment: Exactly which random number generator are you talking about? The default implementation is *not cryptographically secure, nor intended to be*, and any hashing done in the seed algorithm has no cryptographic purpose. It's simply about the requirements of the generator algorithm.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'll try to update the question for a better wording. I am more asking why adding `a` to the hash, provides a better initial seed for the random number generator. The generator python uses is the mersenne twister, which effectively has 624 integer seed variables which need to be properly
initialised at the start. I really do not see how this is more effectively done by adding `a` over not doing it, or if it makes the `seed` more ""random"" so to speak.

Comment: Well, how big do you expect the hash result to be? How many of those 624 integer seed values could you uniquely initialize that way? If you repeat the value for each initial parameter, are you using the full seed space? To my mind, the bigger question is why it appends a hash; my best guess is that's so you don't get *especially* poor results from a *short* `a`.

Comment: That said, a question like this is probably better asked on, for example, the official Python mailing list.

Comment: This might be better suited for Crypto SE, those few people that can actually answer this are probably there too. :) It's not so much a programming question than cryptography. It's a good question though, but maybe not a perfect fit here.

Comment: Actually it's rather the other way around, [the hash got added to `a`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3fcf0029945d8c6f866fdbb98517136999d7be7e#diff-851cf2d8d99b6d8dee26acc31319431dce51dbe26e3e56494d9b4c45edd8e11fL113).

Comment: @KellyBundy Interestingly this doesn't really show the "why". And as it calls it a "salt" I guess that the person that changed the code doesn't really know cryptography in the first place. A salt is kind of a random seed in itself, so by that definition it's not a hash over the data.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I'm not sure what we can answer on [crypto.se] for this. Hashing (i.e. compressing) entropy before entering it into a RNG as seed is not uncommon, but entering both the data and a hash certainly is. N3buchadnezzar: feel free to post a question on why you would provide both data and hash as seed. Implementation details are considered **off topic** though, so beware.

Comment: @Maarten apologies then, I'm not on crypto, maybe that wasn't good advice then, but "it doesn't make sense to do that" is an actual answer if somebody like you with a lot of knowledge on crypto says it :)

Comment: A simple confirmation of "this does not make sense" / does not make sense from a cryptography point of view is exactly what I am after. I totally understand why we hash our input data though. This couple with @KellyBundy's observation that the implementation was the other way around would be a perfect answer. Anyone who wants to piece this toghether for an answer feel free to do so. I will mark it =)